# EF4 and Server Generated UniqueIdentifier Id

Tags: entity-framework

Does Entity Framework 4 not yet support having the guid Id generated at the server upon insert? I have my Id fields set to have a default value of newid(), but Entity Framework is setting the value to the empty guid. I end up with an empty guid in the database and an empty guid in the id field of my object. Is this not yet supported or do I need to changes something on my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Basically the entity framework markup isn't generated properly.

<del>http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/</del>
(broken link, redirects to publicity)

Comment: As you have noticed, the designer & wizards in VS don't keep the SSDL and CSDL in sync; in this case StoreGeneratedPattern but the same applies to many other attributes too. I have a tool that makes it easy to detect & fix that, see the 'model comparer' feature in http://huagati.com/edmxtools/

Comment: @David Osborn the link is broken

Comment: -1: link-answers are not useful; when the links eventually break, like it just did, the answer is not useful.

Comment: Microsoft has a patch now for the mark up bug or using newer versions of Visual Studio should resolve the problem.  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=37957

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the Entity Designer in Visual Studio, which means that updating the "StoreGeneratedPattern" field doesn't correctly update the generated code.  In turn, this means EF passes the entity's GUID to the SQL Server, so the server doesn't run newid() or newsequentialid().

As David says, Microsoft have released a [patch](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=37957).