# Autogenerated Guid Id is empty when updated via Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, guid

To try to isolate the source of a bug I have built the following:

SQL Server table:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Names]
  ([Key] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
   [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,  
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Names] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Key] ASC)
  )
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Names] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Names_Key] DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Key]
```

When I add rows to this table via the SQL Server Management Studio the guid gets a value as expected.

I then create an EF model with this table, this generated the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="Model1", Name="Names")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Names : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new Names object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Initial value of the Key property.</param>
    public static Names CreateNames(global::System.Guid key)
    {
        Names names = new Names();
        names.Key = key;
        return names;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Guid Key
    {
        get
        {
            return _Key;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Key != value)
            {
                OnKeyChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Key");
                _Key = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Key");
                OnKeyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Guid _Key;
    partial void OnKeyChanging(global::System.Guid value);
    partial void OnKeyChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
            _Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnNameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _Name;
    partial void OnNameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnNameChanged();
```

I then created a test to add data to the table:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void WriteTestMethod1()
    {
        using (Model1Container context = new Model1Container())
        {
            Names n = new Names();
            n.Name = "T2";

            context.Names.AddObject(n);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

The result of this is that the row is inserted but the Guid is Empty (all zeros)

Why is this happening? Can EF work with database generated Guids?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF4 and Server Generated UniqueIdentifier Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575322/ef4-and-server-generated-uniqueidentifier-id) and quite a few others

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but here is an answer anyway, since it's still relevant.

- Your test code creates an instance of `class Names` and assigns a value to the `Name` property.
- You don't explicitly assign anything to the Key property.  The Key property is of type Guid, which is a struct (value type), not a class (reference type), so it can never be null and will always have a value, if just the default.  The uninitialized default value of a Guid is all zero fields.
- When you add/persist this entity instance, EF generates an INSERT to both fields, since values exist for both.
- The default value expression defined in your schema is not used because a value was provided in the INSERT statement from the client side.

You can get a server generated uid value by defining the Key field as nullable, which will correspond with field type in C# of `Guid?` (rather than `Guid`).  Then you can allow the Key value to remain null in your code and the server defined default expression will be used.

However, if this field is your primary key, a nullable field may not be what you need.  When I'm in this situation I use a constructor that sets a Guid value (yes, on the client side) rather than allowing it to take the default value.